# How to give readable website name in local IIS7.5 server

Tags: iis-7.5

Till now I was creating website in my local IIS 7.5 server like following way.

```
- Sites
    - AProjects (created this website under Sites & assigned IP address: 192.168.1.100 & Port: 101)
        - websitename1
        - websitename2
        - ... so on
```

For each website I created virtual directory under `Sites >> All FTP Site`

So I was accessing each site using assigned `IP address - Port` like this

```
Example: http://192.168.1.100:101/websitename1
```

But now I want to create websites directly under `Sites` in `IIS7.5` like this.

```
- Sites
    - websitename1 (assigned IP address: 192.168.1.100 & Port: 201) 
    - websitename1 (assigned IP address: 192.168.1.100 & Port: 202)
    - ... so on
```

Now I can access each website like this `http://192.168.1.100:201/user/index.php`

But I want to access it like in this way. `http://websitename1/user/index.php` or something similar to this so it can be more readable.

I read many articles in IIS forum but could not get proper answer. What changes I need to do to get above desired result? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Configure all of the sites to use the same ip address (192.168.1.100) and port (80) and use host headers (Host Name) to differentiate between them.

Comment: I did it as per your guidance. Then I tried to browse website from 'Browse Web Site' option in IIS manager right panel. But it is giving error 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage' in IE. Web address in navigation bar is like this 'http://mysamplesite:80/'

Comment: do you have the names set up in your DNS or in your hosts file? If not, you need to. The names have to resolve to the ip address in order to browse by name.

Comment: I am really sorry but I was totally unaware about it. Can you just provide me tutorial / help link so I can read and implement it. Thank you very much.